# Styles and fonts are loaded after the page has been mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Every time I use Nuxt.js in my projects I encounter the same mistake with styles. Some of them are enabled after the page is mounted. I tried to import styles from a file from a static folder, tried to use styles in the file (tag style), with the scoped attribute, without it, but each time some styles are included after the page has already been mounted. There are no problems in pure Vue js.

Look here, this is the state I was talking about. It lasts about half a second
[image]

And after that the page becomes normal
Sometimes this state persists until the user scrolls the page, sometimes it does not disappear at all

To clarify, I prefer the scoped attribute in my projects, without importing files with styles.

**Edit**

Ok. I don't know will it helps, but there is the code snippets

This is a test page

```
<template>
    <div>
        <app-promo
            :data="{
                titles: ['адреса пиццерий', 'roni napoletana'],
                bgImg: 'page-addresses/promo/promo_bg.png'
            }"
        >
            <app-search></app-search>
        </app-promo>
    </div>
</template>
```

This is a search component

```
<template>
    <div v-click-outside="closeResults" class="search">
        <div class="search__bar">
            <input placeholder="Начните вводить название улицы, чтобы найти ближайшую пиццерию" v-model="searchRequest" @keypress.enter="search" type="text" class="search__input">
            <button @click="search" class="search__submit"><img src="@/static/img/page-addresses/promo/zoom.svg" alt="Search"></button>
        </div>
        <div :class="['search__results', {'search__results_active': showResults}]">
            <nuxt-link 
                :to="item.link" 
                class="search__result" 
                v-for="item in searchedItems" 
                :key="item.title"
            >
                {{ item.title }}
            </nuxt-link>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            searchedItems: [
                {
                    title: 'Истикбол улица',
                    link: '/'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Шевченко улица',
                    link: '/'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Тараккиёт улица',
                    link: '/'
                }
            ],
            searchRequest: '',
            showResults: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        search() {
            this.showResults = true
        },
        closeResults() {
            this.showResults = false
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

This is a promo component

```
<template>
    <section class="promo">
        <div class="promo__bg"><img src="@/static/img/page-main/promo/promo_bg.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="promo__inner">
            <h1 class="promo__title">
                <template v-for="title in data.titles">
                    {{ title }}
                </template>
            </h1>
            <h2 class="promo__subtitle" v-if="data.subtitle">{{ data.subtitle }}</h2>
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
        <div class="promo__label" v-if="data.labelImg">
            <img src="@/static/img/page-main/promo/label_img.svg" alt="Img">
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        data: {
            default: {
                titles: '',
                subtitle: '',
                labelImg: '',
                bgImg: ''
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

My nuxtconfig is standard. The styles are too.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how you think we can help you with just a screenshot. Do you have a public github repo or a [repro]?

Comment: Still not enough since not related to styles at all. Do you have a [repro] or a public Github that we can look into?